# How to empty a file without deleting and creating again using ant tasks?

Tags: ant

> I want to empty the contents of the file but i don't want to truncate the file and create it again.
>   So is there any other option to do this task.

Comment: Please specify the language you want to do this in and also add the same in the question tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).

```
<echo message="" file="/path/to/file.txt"/>
```